# Retrieve value of dynamically created h3 tag

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, cordova, contacts

The suggested current solutions are returning a blank alert for some reason.

I have an h3 tag that is the heading of a jquery mobile collapsible set, its value has been dynamically set to the name of a contact that the user has searched for. Is there any way to retrieve the value of the h3 tag (the contacts name)? It's going to be upon pressing a button that is clicked and eventually it will fill out a form with the contacts credentials but to simplify things right now I am just trying to get it to alert the contacts name to me so i know i've retrieved the contents in the h3 tag. Thanks for your help.

```
for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
    $('#srchResults').append("<div id='resultdiv"+i+"' data-role='collapsible'><h3 id = i>"+contacts[i].name.formatted+"</h3>"+"<p>"+'<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="btnDisguise">'+'Plus'+'</a>'+'<a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext" data-theme="c" data-inline="true" class="btnInfo">'+'Info'+'</a>'+"</p></div>").trigger('create');

}
```

In that mess of code two buttons are created inside of the collapsible. So basically I've been trying to figure out what to put inside of this to retrieve the name inside of the h3:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.btnInfo', function() {
    //alert h3 contents here
});
```

Comment: Give the h3 a unique id and then use `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: You have `<h3 id = i>`, that is you always set the id to the letter `i`, not the value of the variable i. The other thing i thought about, is that you use the name as the key. I don't think that is a good idea, because more than one person can have the exact same name. I always use an integer, and then I can lookup the name of the person of that integer when I need it. When the data is stored in a database, and you want to change the name of the user, it only has to be one change in the table with the names. Every other table identifies the user with its integer, that hasn't changed.

Comment: This reminded me of [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your **h3** tag **ID** needs to start with a alpha character

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.btnInfo', function() {
      //alert h3 contents here
      var $this = $(this),
          h3text = $this.parent().find("h3").text();
      alert(h3text);
});
```

Comment: @Krishna  **h3text** is already declared in the **var** .. thats why there is a **comma** after my **first var** declaration **$this**

Comment: my bad, mistook comma to be a semicolon.

Comment: this solution works to an extent, jquery seems to be interfering because it returns the name and a message on the collapsible's function ex: "John Smith click to collapse contents"

Comment: @siegs could you setup a jsfiddle or codepen so we can see that behavior your seeing being returned ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.btnInfo', function() {
    var result = $(this).parents('#resultdiv').find('h3').text();
    alert(result);
});
```

Since the button is inside the div `#resultdiv` & assuming this `h3` is the first occurrence in that div

Comment: this is just returning a blank alert for some reason